# How do I get the minimum of a pandas datetime series and the (constant) max of another datetime series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Suppose I have two datetime series:

```
foo = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([
    '2020-01-01 12:00:00',
    '2020-02-02 23:12:00'
]))

bar = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([
    '2020-01-20 01:02:03',
    '2020-01-30 03:02:01'
]))
```

Both are of type datetime64[ns]:

```
>>> foo
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00
1   2020-02-02 23:12:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
>>> bar
0   2020-01-20 01:02:03
1   2020-01-30 03:02:01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

For each element in `foo`, I want to get the minimum of:

1. That value from `foo`
2. The (constant) maximum value of `bar`

But this produces a `TypeError`:

```
>>> np.minimum(foo, bar.max())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Timestamp'
```

It works if I just do the `Series` themselves:

```
>>> np.minimum(foo, bar)
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00
1   2020-01-30 03:02:01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`bar.max()` returns a `Timestamp` for some reason, instead of a `datetime64`, but even using an explicit python `datetime` object doesn't work. Why is numpy considering `foo` to be an `int`? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Wouldnt this be the same as min(foo), max(bar)?, what do you mean by `For each element in foo, I want to get the minimum of : That value from foo`. Minimum of a single element is itself. Am i missing something?

Comment: I think they want an element by element minimum of foo versus the maximum of bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
foo.where(foo < bar.max(), bar.max())
```

This replaces values of `foo` with `bar.max()` if the condition (`foo < bar.max())` is `False`.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.  But I have to say I think pandas.Series.where's behavior is exactly the opposite of what I would intuitively have expected.  Why did they make the replacement happen when the condition is false?

Comment: While a little counter intuitive at first glance, I think this is better/more consistent with pandas overall. If other isn't specified it makes nan so doing `foo.where(cond)` gives you foo that meets your condition. Now it behaves sort of like `.loc` where you get what meets your condition.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  It should be thought of more like the optional argument for dict.get(key,, default_value).  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
>>> barmax = bar.max()
>>> barmax
Timestamp('2020-01-30 03:02:01')
>>> foo.map(lambda x: np.minimum(x, barmax))
0   2020-01-01 12:00:00
1   2020-01-30 03:02:01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Comment: It is so strange that this works! Isn't the whole point of numpy that it doesn't matter whether something is a scalar or not? I think there's something about how a scalar datetime64 in pandas is converted into a Timestamp, that's causing this? Maybe even a bug? But this essentially does a for loop through the rows, and my actual data is much bigger so that's not ideal.